# convert data from wide to long using pivot_longer()

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I need your help reshaping data from wide to long, converting multiple cols/variables into rows.

Below is the data.

```
stack1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID, ~Recall1, ~Recall2, ~Recall3,     ~Recall4, ~Recall5,     ~Item1, ~Item2, ~Item3, ~Item4, ~Item5, ~vocab1, ~vocab2, ~vocab3, ~vocab4,
  39,  "Next",   "His",    "University", "Higher", "College",    1,      0,      1,      1,      0,      1,       1,       0,       1,
  90,  "Next",   "her",    "school",     "Higher", "university", 1,      0,      1,      1,      0,      1,       1,       0,       1,
)
```

I want to reshape such that I have only three variables: Recall_value Recog_score, and vocab_sum. The variable vocab_sum represents the sum of vocab1:vocab4 for each ID.

The desired output should be like this:

```
stack2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID, ~Recall,   ~Recall_value, ~Recog,  ~Recog_score, ~vocab_sum,
  39,  "Recall1", "Next",        "Item1", 1,            3,
  39,  "Recall2", "His",         "Item2", 0,            3,
  39,  "Recall3", "University",  "Item3", 1,            3,
  39,  "Recall4", "Higher",      "Item4", 1,            3,
  39,  "Recall5", "College",     "Item5", 0,            3,
  90,  "Recall1", "Next",        "Item1", 1,            4,
  90,  "Recall2", "her",         "Item2", 0,            4,
  90,  "Recall3", "school",      "Item3", 1,            4,
  90,  "Recall4", "Higher",      "Item4", 1,            4,
  90,  "Recall5", "university",  "Item5", 0,            4,
)
```

I have tried the following code using pivot_longer():

```
> stack2 <- stack1 %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        cols =c(`Recall1`:`Recall5`, `Item1`: `Item5`), 
        names_to = c("Recall","Recog"),
        values_to = c("Recall_value", "Recog_score" ))
```

However, it did not help achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two separate pivoting for `Recall` and `Item`.

```
cbind(
stack1 %>% 
  mutate(vocab_sum=vocab1+vocab2+vocab3+vocab4)%>%
  select(-starts_with("vocab"),vocab_sum) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=starts_with("Recall"),
               names_to="Recall",
               values_to="Recall_value") %>%
  select(-(Item1:Item5))
,
stack1 %>% 
  select(-starts_with("vocab")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=starts_with("Item"),
               names_to="Item",
               values_to="Item_value") %>%
  select(-(Recall1:Recall5),-ID)


) |> as_tibble()
```

```
# A tibble: 10 × 6
      ID vocab_sum Recall  Recall_value Item  Item_value
   <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>   <chr>        <chr>      <dbl>
 1    39         3 Recall1 Next         Item1          1
 2    39         3 Recall2 His          Item2          0
 3    39         3 Recall3 University   Item3          1
 4    39         3 Recall4 Higher       Item4          1
 5    39         3 Recall5 College      Item5          0
 6    90         3 Recall1 Next         Item1          1
 7    90         3 Recall2 her          Item2          0
 8    90         3 Recall3 school       Item3          1
 9    90         3 Recall4 Higher       Item4          1
10    90         3 Recall5 university   Item5          0
```

Comment: a small pointer: `-vocab1,-vocab2,-vocab3,-vocab4` can be replaced by `-starts_with("vocab")`, likewise `Recall1:Recall5`

Comment: @Mark thanks. I was reluctant since it may remove `vocab_sum` but it can be override while still inside `select()`

Comment: ah right, I missed that! Alternatively, you could use -vocab1:vocab4, as you had done elsewhere. `.keep = "unused"` is great too

Comment: @Derf see Mark's answer - thanks to the consistent naming system, by using the `names_pattern` argument and the `.value` pronoun in `names_to` it's possible to pivot into multiple columns in one action.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Ah yes thanks for the tip. Forgot to remove that portion from my answer. Also didn't notice that `Recall` and `Item` have the same numbering.  I saw a similar approach to Mark's at `?pivot_longer` but was struggling to understand the regex portion

Comment: Many thanks @Derf for your efforts. It was greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Steps:

1. Create the `vocab_sum` column, by summing all of the vocab values for each row. `.keep = "unused"` then drops all of those vocab columns, as we no longer need them.
2. Pivot non-ID or vocab_sum columns (i.e. the Recall and Item columns) longer, capturing the pattern from their names

```
library(tidyverse)
stack1 |>
  mutate(vocab_sum = rowSums(across(starts_with("vocab"))), .keep = "unused") |>
  pivot_longer(c(starts_with("Recall"), starts_with("Item")), names_to = c(".value", "Recall_num"), names_pattern = "(\\D+)(\\d+)")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 5
      ID vocab_sum Recall_num Recall      Item
   <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <dbl>
 1    39         3 1          Next           1
 2    39         3 2          His            0
 3    39         3 3          University     1
 4    39         3 4          Higher         1
 5    39         3 5          College        0
 6    90         3 1          Next           1
 7    90         3 2          her            0
 8    90         3 3          school         1
 9    90         3 4          Higher         1
10    90         3 5          university     0
```

I assume the column order doesn't matter to you, so I omitted it from the above. But if it is important, you can use `select()` to reorder and rename columns at the same time.

Comment: Thanks @Mark for such an efficient code. It is greatly appreciated. May I ask what does this portion of the code do -->  names_pattern = "(\\D+)(\\d+)").

Comment: yeah sure! so that part is a regular expression- regular expressions are basically fancy pattern matching

Comment: \\d+ matches a digit (0-9) one or more times, and \\D+ matches anything which isn't a digit one or more times

Comment: things inside brackets are called capturing groups. They're used by names_to (hence two values for that

Comment: regular expressions can be a bit like looking at a cryptic code, but they're very good for concisely and unambiguously describing what you're wanting

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/dVA1I9/1

Comment: That was very informative @Mark. Many thanks.